# passing object with useContext, can console log it but cannot use the content of the passed object

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have 2 components `GrillePratiques` and `GrilleExercices`, they are children on `AppLayout` and I pass a state `lastPratique` from `GrillePratiques` to `GrilleExercices` via a useContext provider in AppLayout (`lastPratiqueProvider`)

I have an object `nudges` in GrilleExercices from which I try to read a value with the key `lastPratique`

`lastPratique` passes correctly in `GrilleExercices` (i can console log it)
When i try to read `nudges.lastPratique` it says undefined

```
export default function Grille() {
  const { lastPratique, lastPratiqueRef } = useLastPratique();
  console.log(lastPratique);
  console.log(lastPratiqueRef.current);

  console.log(nudges.lastPratique);
```

returns the value (`B1_logique`) for the console.log(lastPratique) but undefined for the console.log(nudges.lastPratique):

@react-refresh:278 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'current')
at Grille (GrilleExercices.jsx:1220:38)

**extract of GrilleExercice:**

```
const nudges = {
  B1_logique: {
    nudge1:
      "Lorem ipsum",
    nudge2:
      "Lorem ipsum",
 
  },
...
export default function Grille() {
  const { lastPratique, lastPratiqueRef } = useLastPratique();
  console.log(lastPratique);
  console.log(lastPratiqueRef.current);

  console.log(nudges.lastPratique);
```

**extract of AppLayout
**

```
<LastPratiqueProvider
      lastPratique={lastPratique}
      setLastPratique={setLastPratique}
      lastPratiqueRef={lastPratiqueRef}
    >
      <SujetsProvider sujetsRef={sujetsRef} setSujetsRef={setSujetsRef}>
        <StyledAppLayout>
          <Header />
          <Sidebar />
          <SuggestionsContext.Provider value={suggestions}>
            <Main>
              <Nudge />
              <Outlet />
              {/* <GrillesLayout /> */}
            </Main>
          </SuggestionsContext.Provider>
        </StyledAppLayout>
      </SujetsProvider>
    </LastPratiqueProvider>
```

**extract of LastPratiqueContextProvider where is LastPratiqueProvider**

```
import { LastPratiqueContext } from "./LastPratiqueContext";
import { useContext } from "react";

function useLastPratique() {
  const context = useContext(LastPratiqueContext);
  return context;
}

function LastPratiqueProvider({
  lastPratique,
  setLastPratique,
  lastPratiqueRef,
  children,
}) {
  // UseLastPratique();
  return (
    <LastPratiqueContext.Provider
      value={{
        lastPratique: lastPratique,
        setLastPratique: setLastPratique,
        lastPratiqueRef: lastPratiqueRef,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </LastPratiqueContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { useLastPratique, LastPratiqueProvider };
```

. I thought it may be that react reads `nudges.lastPratique` before render and it may be undefined, so I tried to create a reference lastPratiqueRef in GrillePratiques and pass it but it is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nudges` does not have a `lastPratique` property. So `nudges.lastPratique` is `undefined`.

```js
const nudges = {
  B1_logique: {
    nudge1:
      "Lorem ipsum",
    nudge2:
      "Lorem ipsum",
 
  },
```

The array notation (a.k.a. [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation)) (e.g: `object[expression]`) evaluates `expression` and uses the result as the `object`'s key:

```
console.log(lastPratique) // B1_logique
console.log(nudges[lastPratique]) // { nudge1: "Lorem ipsum", ...}
```

`nudges[lastPratique]` is the equivalent of `nudges["B1_logique"]` (or `nudges.B1_logique`), because `lastPratique` evaluates as `"B1_logique"`.

Comment: Thanks you very much Tao, I Learned something ! Have a nice week end